# Find and replace n characters long random string in Notepad++ using wildcards/regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have a SQL dump with expressions such as `youtubehd:2nj6bykw`. The `2nj6bykw` can also be a different random string. It is always 8 characters long.

I want to replace `youtubehd:2nj6bykw` with just `youtubehd`.

How can I do this without replacing it manually, one by one? The SQL dump is over 230000 lines long and has about 200 occurrences of these strings.

I suppose I need a wildcard, but I have no clue about what it is and how I can do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please make sure you have a backup in case something goes wrong.

- In Notepad++ go to **Search → Replace**
- In the *Find What* textbox paste the following: `youtubehd:\w\w\w\w\w\w\w\w`
- In the *Replace With* textbox paste the following: `youtubehd`
- Ensure that *Search Mode* is set to **Regular expression**
- Click **Replace All**

Thanks to KCotreau for pointing out that search mode defaults to Normal and needs to be changed.

**Edit:**

It's been pointed out in the comments below that you could instead use `youtubehd:\w{8}` as your search pattern. This is correct and indeed preferable. Support for this was only added in Notepad++ v6 though which came out after this was originally written hence the reason why I used the longer form. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819957/notepadsearching-an-regex-expression-n-times) for more.

Comment: +1 I have been beating myself up trying to figure this out. It should be so simple, but it was not easy to find. I tested this and it does work. I would add: Choose "Regular Expression" for the search type.

Comment: More elegant would be: `youtubehd:\w{8}` for fixed lenth and `youtubehd:\w*` for any

Comment: @AndriuZ: I was aware of the `\w{8}` syntax but to my knowledge Notepad++ didn't support it at the time and I believe it was added in a later version. I'll probably update the answer to reflect this at some point.

Comment: @James P it worked when I tested on Np++ 7.4.2 32bit